# Extracting extents of the map view in QGIS

Tags: qgis, extents

Status bar in QGIS can display min/max of x/y for extents of the map view when panning and zooming. How can these values be extracted and used in expressions? The manual’s [expression page](http://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression) doesn’t seem to have variables for current map view extents.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. You can use the python console with this command to extract the bounds of the map extent: `extent = iface.mapCanvas().extent()`

Comment: Thank you. Can this method be used in label creation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean the extent of the canvas (the view in the main window)?

This can be accessed using the `@map_extent` variable in Expression Builder which returns a polygon of the current canvas map extent.

You can then use `min_x()`, `min_y()` etc. to extract bounding box coordinates for use in your labels, or to guide your label placement using data defined override.

See below for an example of labels that update based on the map canvas extent. The expression uses `min_x(@map_extent)` and `min_y(@map_extent)` and then the distance from the point `$geometry` to the SW corner of the canvas (`make_point()` of the min_x/min_y values).

[image]

Comment: Marvellous! I used `z_max(@map_extent) ≶ #` and it’s working great. For the record, the order in the variable is `z_min()`, which is what you might want to change to in your answer.